# Why MVC is generating route with weird parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am getting url routes like this in firebug:

```
http://<host>/user/bob/GetFollowers?pageno=2&_=1395084415411
```

Why the url has `&_=1395084415411` at the end?
I checked the ajax call, I am not adding\passing the _=1395084415411 parameter

This is my route configuration:

```
context.MapRoute(
  "Action",
  "user/{id}/{action}",
   new { action = "index", controller = "MyController" },
   new string[] { "App.Controllers" }
   );
```

Here is the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetFollowers(string id, int pageno){
}
```

EDIT:
I am using a plugin to make all ajax request.
Here is the part that sends the call:

```
$.ajax({
                url: this.url,
                cache: false,
                type: this.method,
                data: (this.method.toUpperCase() === "GET") ? this.params.toObject() : JSON.stringify(this.params.toObject()),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: Function.reference(this, this.success),
                error: Function.reference(this, this.error),
                async: this.getAsync()
            });
```

Comment: Are you making these calls from AJAX?

Comment: Ok, are you sending the type as 'jsonp'?

Comment: I updated the question. Now the only issue is extra _ parameter

Comment: Can you post the AJAX request as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the additional stuff in your url is there to make your request unique. if you set cache:true in your ajax object, you should no longer see that extra bit.

Comment: What is the recommended practice? I didn't have to deal with caching issue with regards to performance on Ajax Requests...

Comment: I personally would ignore the additional querystring as some browsers (Chrome, Firefox) automatically add it to the request unless you specifically set the cache property to true (which I assume is something you don't want to do??). IE on the other hand always assume cache=true so it doesn't add the querystring by default.

Comment: jQuery `.ajax` [reference](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) confirming use of cache setting adding `_=` _timestamp_ .

Answer (score 0):

The additional '&_=1395084415411' is going to be a function callback for JSONP.  It should not interfere with your actual data sent/received.  You may be making the call with a dataType: 'jsonp'.

Comment: Since jsonp is not same as json, I am not using jsonp as dataType, See my code above.